# Laravel Custom Error Pages & Error Handling

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to show suggestions related to its model if the model is not found. Let say User is accessing Job ABC21, but this job is no longer exist, and therefore Laravel displays an 404 Error page. Laravel by default only shows 404 Error Title and Message, however I want to change them by displaying list of Jobs suggestions.

Same scenario goes to other models.

I know that we can modify the view of 404 Error page by creating `404.blade.php` inside `resources/views/errors`. But it only change the view.

How can I work around on this?

Thank You

Comment: Here's an article on how to catch exceptions (like data not found) and show custom messages or pages. https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-catch-handle-create-laravel-exceptions/

Comment: The same guys also have one for when your API blows up. https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-api-errors-and-exceptions-how-to-return-responses/